# How can I properly use the 'sed' s command in this particular scenario

Tags: bash, sed, string

I have a names.txt file where each line is of the form:

```
xxxxxx   random_string_of_characters    2015
```

where xxxxxx is a 6-digit number, and random_string_of_characters can be **anything**. I want to use the substitute command to replace all the empty space and the random_string_of_characters between xxxxxx and 2015 in each row, so that each string looks like this:

```
xxxxxx 2015
```

So, what would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you are not wedded to sed: `awk '{print $1,$3}'`...

Comment: @jasonwryan - I'd use `$NF` instead of `$3` just to be sure as _"random_string_of_characters can be anything"_

Comment: @don_crissti Good point.

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
sed -i -e 's/[[:space:]]\+.\+2015$/ 2015/' names.txt
```

If you want to save it into the same file.  Drop the `-i` if you just want to print to stdout, which you could redirect into another file.

It will match any number of spaces followed by anything up to 2015 at the end of the line, then replace that whole match with " 2015"

Another possibility would be to do

```
sed -e 's/^\([[:digit:]]\{6\}\).\+\([[:digit:]]\{4\}\)$/\1 \2/'  names.txt
```

Which will match 6 digits at the start of the line and 4 at the end and print those matches with a space between them.  It will leave any other lines unchanged.

Comment: Since you're using 2015 in the _RHS_ there's no point using it in the _LHS_ too so `sed 's/[[:blank:]].*/ 2015/'` would do. If last four digits aren't always the same you could use `sed 's/[[:blank:]].*[[:blank:]]/ /'`

Comment: Provided the 2015 isn't crucial to matching some lines I like both of your solutions.

Comment: Well, I assume it isn't, as per the OP: _"where each line is of the form..."_

Answer (score 0):

my preference is to anchor to the start of the string to reduce back tracking and I like extended regexp so I would use

```
sed -re 's/^([0-9]{6}) .*( 2015)$/\1\2/' names.txt
```

what this does

```
-r extended regexp
-e expression to follow
s substitute
^ beginning of line
( start subpattern
[0-9] a digit
{6} previous occurs exactly six times
) end subexpression
. any single character
* previous occurs zero or more times
$ end of line
\1 first subpattern
\2 second subpattern
```

Comment: If empty space = tab this won't work; just remove the spaces from the expression, e.g. `sed -E 's/^([0-9]{6}).*(2015)$/\1 \2/'` would work in all cases